# How to access value in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have directive as follow :

```
directive('checkKey', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                min: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                elem.bind('keypress', function(event) {
                   if (event.keyCode === 46 || event.keyCode === 45) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    } else if (event.key < scope.min) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    })
```

But i am not able to access the input model value...

Answer (score 1):

You need to require ngModel, then inject ngModelCtrl into your link. The value will be in the ngModelCtrl.

```
directive('checkKey', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                min: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

                // this would give you the ngModel value also.
                var ngModelVal = $parse(attrs.ngModel);

                elem.bind('keypress', function(event) {
                   if (event.keyCode === 46 || event.keyCode === 45) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    } else if (event.key < scope.min) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: console.log(ngModelVal); giving me function

Comment: @Rhushikesh $parse will give you the function to execute. You should use $parse along with scope `var ngModelVal = $parse(attrs.ngModel)(scope)`

Answer (score 0):

You can `require` the `ngModel` controller inside your directive. You can set the ngModel value via `$setViewValue` and access the value via `$modelValue`

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('myDirective', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            console.log("$modelValue", ngModel);
            ngModel.$render = function() {
                $timeout(function() {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue('I am updated');  
                }, 5000);                
            };
        }
    };
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Vinoth';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x7xb0w26/